# Can't compile pgbouncer neither in linux nor in windows

Tags: c, windows, mingw, configure, pgbouncer

I'm trying compile pgbouncer to use in a PostgreSQL server running in windows server 2008. However I simply can't compile the dll, and the same error appears in linux (ubuntu) and in windows:

> checking for libevent... configure: error: not found: cannot proceed

I'm following [this howto](http://pgbouncer.github.io/install.html). I've compiled the **libevent** in windows using **mingw** and copied the dlls generated to System32, SysWOW64 and even in own pgbouncer directory. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Never copy random dll's to `C:\Windows`. That's terrible in all ways possible.

Comment: For Windows, if at all possible find prebuilt binaries. For Linux, install pgbouncer from packages; see apt.postgresql.org and yum.postgresql.org

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`configure` is checking whether it will be possible for the package build
to link `libevent`. For that it needs see that `libevent` *development*
dependencies are satisfied. It checks not only that `libevent` itself can be found
for linkage but that the header `<event.h>` (exactly like that) can be
found for compilation.

For `configure` to succeed you must make sure that:-

- `event.h` from your `libevent` package will be found in the default or
  configured include-search paths of the compiler.
- The `libevent` binary will be found in the default or configured library-search
  paths of the linker.

Near the top of the [HowTo](http://pgbouncer.github.io/install.html) that you
have referred to you will see that `configure` accepts a parameter
`--with-libevent=libevent-prefix` that can make this easy. `./configure --help`
says:

```
--with-libevent=prefix  Specify where libevent is installed
```

For your ubuntu system the short answer would be: install `libevent-dev` from
the package manager. In Ubuntu you could also install `pgbouncer` from
the package manager, but perhaps you want the latest version.

Comment: Thank you. I've added prefix and reinstalled libevent in windows. Then used that in --with-libevent.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install libevent-devel, that supplies 2 event.h files:

```
# find / -name event.h 2>/dev/null 
/usr/include/event.h
/usr/include/event2/event.h
```

To install run:

```
yum install libevent-devel.x86_64
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compile pgBouncer for Windows, follow my instructions under https://sepppenner.github.io/PgBouncerWinBinaries/ or https://github.com/SeppPenner/PgBouncerWinBinaries.